# why setTimeout and setiImidiate are deterministic only in IO cycle

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

In node the documentation [here](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/#setimmediate-vs-settimeout), it is said that the output of setTimeout and setImmidiate being called together is non-deterministic.

i understand that,
 but what follows it is an example of using an IO wrapper callback

```
fs.readFile(__filename, () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('timeout');
  }, 0);
  setImmediate(() => {
    console.log('immediate');
  });
});
```

which makes the order always be:

```
    sesetImmidiate 
    setTimeout
```

with the following explanation:
*The main advantage to using setImmediate() over setTimeout() is setImmediate() will always be executed before any timers if scheduled within an I/O cycle, independently of how many timers are present.*

why exactly '*setImmediate() will always be executed before any timers if scheduled within an I/O cycle*'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of `libuv` design, in [this](https://jsblog.insiderattack.net/handling-io-nodejs-event-loop-part-4-418062f917d1) article you can find a complete explanation how this works, here's a summary:

Libuv order execution:

```
while (r != 0 && loop->stop_flag == 0) {
     // first timers
    uv__update_time(loop);
    uv__run_timers(loop);
    ran_pending = uv__run_pending(loop);
    uv__run_idle(loop);
    uv__run_prepare(loop);

    timeout = 0;
    if ((mode == UV_RUN_ONCE && !ran_pending) || mode == UV_RUN_DEFAULT) {
      timeout = uv_backend_timeout(loop);
    }

    uv__io_poll(loop, timeout);
    uv__run_check(loop);           // check handlers - "setImmediate"
    uv__run_closing_handles(loop);

    if (mode == UV_RUN_ONCE) {
     // second timers
      uv__update_time(loop);
      uv__run_timers(loop);
    }

    r = uv__loop_alive(loop);
    if (mode == UV_RUN_ONCE || mode == UV_RUN_NOWAIT)
      break;
  }
```

> 1. uv__loop_alive — Check whether there are any referenced handlers to be
>      invoked, or any active operations pending
> 2. uv__update_time — This
>      will send a system call to get the current time and update the loop
>      time (This is used to identify expired timers).
> 3. uv__run_timers — Run
>      all expired timers
> 4. uv__run_pending — Run all completed/errored I/O
>      callbacks
> 5. uv__io_poll — Poll for I/O
> 6. uv__run_check — Run all check
>      handlers (setImmediate callbacks will run here)
> 7. uv__run_closing_handles — Run all close handlers

Both `setTimeout` and `setImmediate` are macrotasks, here's why are executed in that order, nice discussion about this [here](https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/1118):

> If scripts have been scheduled by **setImmediate()**, "polling" phase will
>   set a time-out which is zero.It means that after the queue has been
>   exhausted, "polling" phase will not wait for callbacks to be added to
>   the queue but continue to the check phase.
>
> If scripts have been
>   scheduled by **setTimeout()**, "polling" will set a time-out which is the
>   result of the soonest threshold of timers minus current time.Then when
>   time out, the loop continues and finally wraps back to the timers
>   phase.